# Renaming Android App eliminates it in some Searches in Market

Tags: google-play

I renamed my app about 6 months ago, and I've been hearing reports every once in a while that some people cannot find my app in the market. Finally, someone I knew had the problem where I could look at it. My old name was a very unique name, my new name is a few common words. So it used to be:

com.company.uniquename : Uniquename

Now it is:

com.company.uniquename : Blee Blah Bloo

If I search the new name on my tablet, my app shows up 2nd behind a totally unrelated app. However if you search "Uniquename" it still shows up (as the only result). However on my friends device, nothing shows up if you search "Blee Blah Bloo". She scanned the QR code linking to my app and could download and run it fine. Do you have any thoughts as to why it wouldn't be showing up on some devices. It is a high maturity app, could that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

It takes some time for google to re-index your app after you rename it.  I expect given a few days, your app will show in related search queries, also taking into account the popularity of your app.

Comment: btw, Blee Blah Bloo is a genius app name!